# Nacho's girlfriends -- reason for not murdering them?

Tags: plot-explanation, better-call-saul

A very unusual (I can't think of anything similar in any crime movie I have watched) scene occurs when Mike and his men in preparation for the replacement of Nacho's safe in a surprisingly patient and humane way (considering who they are) enter Nacho's apartment and Mike tells the two women that they absolutely must leave.

Mike is gruff but understanding -- it seems like he knows of them which implies that the Salamancas must also, they are no big secret -- and says, You need to go to your families; if you don't have family, go to friends; and if you don't have friends, makes some. But you must never return.

Part of this is that they have very important things to do that the women should not observe. But also, I think Mike is concerned somewhat for their safety if the Salamancas find them -- they would almost certainly torture them for what they might know.

But the problem is, they actually might know something -- there is the woman who has become psychotic through meth use and the other one whom has things more together and Nacho may, isolated as he is from anyone he can talk to, have told her things.

So Mike is relying on those women really leaving Albuquerque immediately and for good. This is best for them and essential for Gus. But safest for Gus would be to have them killed -- they don't seem reliable, they are dependent on Nacho and the amount of money looked to be between 5k and 10k -- not a lot. If they run out of money, they could well decide to haunt the old place, like stray dogs or cats who have been abandoned by their owners. Or just be found somewhere in the city, maybe the Salamancas have people with their photos at the bus station or airport.

Perhaps Mike made his, "They are not in the game" speech to Gus -- do we know anything more about why the two floozies were allowed to live, maybe from an interview with one of the actors or writers?

Answer (score 4):

There's no reason to kill the girls. Mike knows that Nacho is way too smart, experienced, and disciplined to share valuable secrets with his junkie girlfriends. The Salamancas would know this too.

Remember how shocked Mike was to learn that Saul had shared some information with Kim? Mike couldn't believe that Saul would be do something that stupid, even though Saul was a newcomer to the game. Nacho would never do something that stupid.

The reason Mike wants the girls to leave town is because he knows Nacho is never coming back, and the disappearance will go smoother if the girls are out of the picture.

Answer (score 3):

Who among the Salamancas would have photos of Amber and Jo? Who left among the Salamancas would even know of them? Tuco, maybe but he's in prison, the cartel probably can't get a message to and from him fast enough to have people in place at any airports. Hector isn't in a position to describe them in a manner that wouldn't take hours, if not days to relay. Lalo is, as far as the cartel is concerned, dead. And the cartel don't have direct contact with anyone else north of the border from the Salamanca organisation.

The risk and expense of letting the women go is minimal, probably less than the risk and expense of "disposing" of them by more traditional gangster means. But the look on their faces was genuine and Mike could be fairly certain they'd do what they were told for fear of what might happen if they did not.

$10k may not be much in the context of the show, where we see Gus deliver shrink-wrapped bundles of cash to Eladio, or where Heisenberg has amassed enough cash that a guy of Huell's size can use it as a bed with enough room left over for Kuby, but it's going to be enough for those two women to get away from Albuquerque and tide them over until they get a new source of income.

Although it's not shown, it's possible a brief word was exchanged between Mike (or possibly Tyrus) and Nacho about Amber and Jo, and how much they knew. Judging from what we'd little we've seen of his home life, it's likely Nacho told them nothing of use.

This choice of action definitely fits what we know of Mike; not killing unless he feels there are no other choices left, and using his ability to read people, learned from years on the police force, to know what someone is going to do.

This choice also fits what we know of Gus; willing to take small risks to appease Mike's sensibilities, and trusting Mike's read on people.

Comment: The Twins easily found Mike's family. As thuggish as the Salamancas appear, we have gotten glimpses which demonstrate that they have their shit together -- the vast compound that served as a garage and vault. They run a business worth many hundreds of millions and I assume they have people who spy for them etc. Anyway, 100% they knew about the floozies because it was in their interest to know about them. Do you think Lalo plays poker for such small stakes for fun with his men? No, it is to learn about them in a seemingly friendly setting. Floozies cd have been at parties, etc.

Comment: Where do you live where 10k (or 5k) is enough to keep two people, one of whom is an addict, going for more than a couple months? I bet both those girls, assuming they have no families, indeed are on the streets pretty fast. I actually like them -- the smart one seems sweet and protective of the dumb one and I hope things worked out for them but I am not optimistic. Frankly, becoming hookers seems likely -- I am sure Mike would agree with me.

Comment: We agree without Mike's intercession, the two would have been killed with no deliberation. It's a lousy business that we see destroys everyone involved, especially the powerless.

Comment: We don't see how quickly the Salamancas took to find Mike's family. The cousins were busy searching for Nacho, and we've seen that the rest of the personnel are much less competent. Lalo was presumed dead, so he wouldn't be able to offer any insight.

Comment: I figure they have an entire "HR" department. You saw that counting room? A big, complex organization. What is actually a little unrealistic is Hector, the head of this empire, sitting in the front of a cheap Mexican restaurant but perhaps what they wanted to show is: No matter how big Hector got, he remained a street hood. Just like Lalo:  Clearly an intelligent man with his own hacienda and able to talk intelligently to Werner's widow, Lalo nonetheless seemed happy to literally get his hands dirty. Eladio and Bolsa were different, real "drug lords."

Comment: They may have plenty of people, but none show a fraction of the skills of Lalo, or the cousins, or Nacho for that matter. Also, they're all south of the border, trying to find Nacho. Getting a message to someone in Albuquerque to get someone to Nacho's place and secure the women there was probably low on their list of priorities at that point. When they couldn't find him, Bolsa took the job on personally. Whether he had been briefed by the Salamancas into Nacho's live-in companions is unlikely, as I don't recall any suggestion from him that anything seemed amiss (such as their absence).

Comment: "probably less than the risk and expense of "disposing" of them by more traditional gangster means" — for reals. A stainless steel fridge here, a car-disposal trip to California there, and pretty soon you're talking real money.

Comment: Walter really streamlined the "inconvenient corpse disposal" methodology for Gus' whole operation. Gus really should have been more appreciative.